# Finding fastest path that do not exceed specified cost

Tags: algorithm

I'm having a problem with finding fastest path that do not exceed specified cost.

Let's say I've got specified maximum cost,  and 4 records.

```
// specified cost
    10 
// end point
    5
//(start point) (finish point) (time) (cost)
    2 5 50 5
    3 5 20 9
    1 2 30 5
    1 3 30 7
```

I have to decide, whether It's possible to get from point (1) to (5) (its impossible when theres no path that costs <= than we've got or when theres no connection between 1-5) and if so, what would be the fastest way to get in there.

The output for such data would be:

```
80 // fastest time
3 1 // number of points that (1 -> 2)  -> (2 -> 5)
```

Keep in mind, that if there's a record saying you can move **1->2**

```
1 2 30 5
```

It doesnt allow you to move **2<-1**.

Comment: This sounds like the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) to me.

Comment: It's just an application of the [shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) on a digraph.  Find the shortest path, if it's of higher weight than the maximum, then the answer is no, otherwise the answer is what you have found. [Dijstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is probably the simplest way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic programming, something like this:

```
Route(node, length, target, accumulated)

if length <= 0 return -1
if node == target return accumulated

For each adjacent node:
  current length = accumulated + Route(adjacent node, length - connecting edge weight, target, accumulated + connecting edge weight)
  min length = min(current length, min length)

return min length
```

Comment: Interesting, but this solution is pseudo-polynomial. I wonder if there is a polynomial one.

Comment: @amit it's a simplified Dijkstra (some details should be added for full solution I suppose), you can't do better than Dijkstra

Comment: It is not simplified dijkstra, since the solution complexity is a function of `length` (linear) - and since `length` is `2^NUM_BITS_NEEDED_TO_REPRESENT_LENGTH` it is pseudo-polynomial, while dijkstra is polynomial.

Comment: @amit I'm not sure why did you introduce number of bits for length, the complexity of graph traversal is usually given as a function of vertices and edges number. This algorithm runtime is `O(|V|*|E|)`, while Dijkstra's is `O(|E|+|V|log|V|)`, which is obviously better but both are polynomial since `O(|E|) = O(|V^2|)`.

Comment: Well, I'll find the fastest path using Dijkstras algorithm. What if fastest path is too expensive? I've got to find fastest way that do not exceed specified cost. I might be wrong but I'm convienced Dijkstra's algorithm wont do that. Just like in my example, Dijkstra algorithm would output (1 ->3) -> (3 -> 5) (time: 50, cost: 16). However, It's cost is 16 and our maximum cost is 10, so the output will be (1 -> 2)  -> (2 -> 5) (time: 80, cost: 10)

Comment: @Patryk just add a stop condition that checks whether the maximum cost has been reached, something like in the pseudocode in my answer

Comment: btw, Is fact, that the points from the records can only point from lower to higher [ (1->2) possible, (2->1) impossible ] changing anything?

Comment: You can skip the last iteration if the outcome will evidently exceed the maximum. Maybe you can use some additional heuristics to cut more paths, but that might result in more complexity than usefulness

Answer (score 0):

A web search finds http://www.cs.elte.hu/~alpar/publications/jour/AKCE_October_25.pdf suggesting that it is a reasonably current research problem. Without reading the paper, my approach would be to use dynamic programming where, for each node, you keep a record of the shortest path with cost <= K, for each sensible K. You need only keep K values where the shortest path available changes as K changes. This might be feasible if either the cost or the time were reliably small integers. If not, you can construct example problems that require you to compute and keep unmanageable numbers of partial solutions.

Comment: That sounds a lot more general than this question.